# How to merge to local datasets in spark scala 2.11.11

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 local files that I am reading into spark scala 2.11.11.  The first file has 5 columns and the second file has 3 columns.  There is one id column that is in both files.
I have tried using the merge function, but, that is not working.

Can someone help me with merging these 2 files and display the top 100 records?

```
df1
pId
routeId
from
to
date
```

```
df2
pId
firstName
lastName
```

Desired output:

```
pId, firstName, lastName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which `merge` function you were trying to use, but you can just join these two dataframes

```scala
df
.join(df2, Seq("pid"))
.select("pid", "firstName", "lastName")
```

Look at join signature and its overloadings in the [scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)

Comment: the join works, but, what about displaying the top 100 records?

Comment: In the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@join(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],joinExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) you can also find method `show` with different overloadings